# C modulos and Remainders

Tags: c, modulo

Hey, I'm having the toughest time figuring out how to display this result. Say for example I enter a number such as 59. Based off that number, I get a remaining result of 1 week(s) 2 Day(s) and 5 Hour(s). This is of course assuming one week has 40 hours and 1 day has 7 hours in order to get that output. Any help in the right direction would be helpful. So far I've set it up like so:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &totalWeeksWorked, &totalDaysWorked, &totalHoursWorked);
```

Comment: What `scanf` is supposed to do there?

Comment: I'm just having it scan the three variable outputs that will be displayed. There's more code I just wanted to show a little snippet, sorry about not being clear enough.

Comment: @user520720: Did you mean to use printf to print the outputs that will be displayed?

Comment: Just FYI, but 7 hour days don't add up to a 40 hour week.

Comment: This is obviously a homework assignment with a totally misguided and fake attempt to "show one's work so far"...

Comment: @AndreyT: Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by ineptitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int const HOURS_PER_WEEK = 40;
int const HOURS_PER_DAY = 7;

int main() {
  int total_hours = 59;  // this is the input you get

  int remaining = total_hours;  // 'remaining' is scratch space

  int weeks = remaining / HOURS_PER_WEEK;
  remaining %= HOURS_PER_WEEK;

  int days = remaining / HOURS_PER_DAY;
  remaining %= HOURS_PER_DAY;

  int hours = remaining;

  printf("%d hours = %d weeks, %d days, %d hours\n",
         total_hours, weeks, days, hours);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I really like how you structured that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the fastest way, but is perhaps the most illustrative:

```
int numodweeks = input/(7*24);
int numofdays  =input/24;
int numofhours = 24 - (input/24);
```

Using modulo:

```
        int numofweeks = input/(7*24);
        int numofdays = (input%numofweeks)/7;
        int numofhours = (input%(numofdays*24));
```

Then display them how you want.

Comment: I tried that at first initially, but I'm trying to figure out a way to use the remainder operator to display that. I'll probably re-factor this once I'm done and use your method above. Appreciate the input though!

Comment: Is it nessisary to use that operator, or do you just think that is a good way to do it?

Comment: I like both ways but I'm trying to get more comfortable using that operator. I'm not so familiar with using it, and I just thought it would be best to use it in this instance. Do you know a way of doing that?